# Getting back to default SageMaker Studio Lab project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I wanted to start fresh and delete the things I had added to my project, and I think I may have messed up and deleted like all the important files my one and only studiolab project needs. For example, I got the error `bash: sudo: command not found` which I don't remember happening before hand. In the lab I only have options to stop and start my runtime or open my project. Is there any way I can just start fresh from the way it was before I screwed it up? Like a default image or something? And without using the actual studio or a notebook I'd have to pay for. Just my lab.

I tried some rm command I saw online and I think it deleted everything important. I also removed every conda environment but the base one. I'd like to get back to where it was before I meddled.